# Querying a bytea field using postgrex

Tags: postgrex

I'm attempting to query a table in postgres with the following:

```
result =
    Postgrex.query!(pg, "SELECT owner_id, connected_at FROM devices WHERE id = $1", [device_id])
# result = []
```

The `device_id` variable is an Elixir string, and this query used to work when the `id` and `owner_id` columns were `text`. But they've been changed to `bytea` and my query is now not returning any rows.

There *is* a single matching row in the table. How do I fix this?